# From Listbox item to a textbox with duplicate items

Tags: c#, .net, c, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have 1 listbox and 2 buttons and 2 textboxes. When i press a button my listbox shows + all my data.

In the listbox i have around 30 names. With different names in it. Some names are the same.

And when i press the other button so shall in one textbox (that i already done). Show a name that i selected in the list. But! Here comes the tricky part.

I want to have in the last textbox the name from a listbox that can calculate all names that are in the same name.

If i selected "Peter" in the list and Peter is 3-4 times in that list. How can i write it out so it displays 3 times? I mean 3 (int) times.

And here is the Code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _items.Add("Per Lindmark, 2012-05-01");
       // add more items
        _items.Add("Elin Ivarsson, 2012-05-13");

        listBox1.DataSource = _items;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.

```
var name = txtBox1.Text.Split(' ')[0];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
     return;
}
var items = listBox1.DataSource as List<string>;
var count = items.Count(x => x.Split(' ')[0] == name);
textBox2.Text = count.ToString();
```

I hope I understood your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over all items in the list and compare the names:

```
int counter = 0;    
foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
{
    if (item == name)
        counter++;
}
```

Of course, you'd have to extract the name from the item in the list properly.